# How to use SMI function on a lagged price

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to use SMI on a lagged price so at first I  wrote this simple line of code :
 `SPY$SMI3MA <- SMI(SPY[,c("SPY.High","SPY.Low","SPY.Close")], maType=list(list(SMA), list(EMA, wilder=TRUE), list(SMA)) )`  then I turned this column to a laaged one by using this line:
`SPY$SMI3MA_T <- Lag(SPY$SMI3MA  , k = 1 )`
But I got only the MA results and not the SMI as can be seen in the output below.
How can I fix this code so I'll get the SMI result on the lagged price ?
Here is the code:

```
spy<-getSymbols(("SPY") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2007-01-01', auto.assign = T)

 spy<-cbind(SPY)
 SPY$SMI3MA <- SMI(SPY[,c("SPY.High","SPY.Low","SPY.Close")], maType=list(list(SMA), list(EMA, wilder=TRUE), list(SMA)) )
 SPY$SMI3MA_T <- Lag(SPY$SMI3MA  , k = 1 )
 tail(SPY)
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted        SMI    SMI3MA  SMI3MA_T
2016-02-11   182.34   184.10  181.09    182.86  210592800       182.86 -16.107562 -14.38172 -15.34089
2016-02-12   184.96   186.65  183.96    186.63  124459300       186.63 -17.289562 -14.03284 -14.38172
2016-02-16   188.77   189.81  187.63    189.78  112124300       189.78 -16.383093 -13.93242 -14.03284
2016-02-17   191.16   193.32  191.01    192.88  131884500       192.88 -13.668168 -13.79414 -13.93242
2016-02-18   193.20   193.27  191.72    192.09   98872300       192.09 -10.379016 -13.59036 -13.79414
2016-02-19   191.17   192.18  190.45    192.00  111764300       192.00  -7.307641 -13.22583 -13.59036
```

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is, or what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this function (SMI) based on a 1 day lagged data: As I understand the SMI uses the current day's High,Low,Close but I would like to use one day lagged : Lag(SPY$SPY.High, k=1 ) etc..How can I do It ?

Comment: `SMI(Lag(HLC(SPY), k=1))`

Comment: Thank you @Joshua Ulrich

Comment: Yet I still get : Error in xts(new.x, x.index) : NROW(x) must match length(order.by)

Comment: Use `lag` instead of `Lag`: `SMI(lag(HLC(SPY), 1))`. Looks like `Lag` doesn't like multivariate input.